# Migrating liquibase from version 3.5.3 to 4.8.0 causes databasechangelog md5sum column being set to NULL

Tags: postgresql, liquibase, java-11

As written in the title, I've started migrating liquibase from 3.5.3 version to the 4.8.0
and when I start migration, instead of updating md5sum column of databasechangelog table for those 3.5.3 entries to the new checksum value it is updated to NULL and never recalculated. 
For such a migration i am calling Java Liquibase#update(Contexts contexts, LabelExpression labelExpression) method, and underlying database that I am using is postgreSQL. No error is thrown, it's just md5sum column being overriden with NULL value.
New migrations are getting correct md5sum value, looking somthing like `8:92a9dbde7a04a1d2ee1aec16beaf0d6b`.
Is anyone else having similar issue? Found [this](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/issues/2580), but even when I updated my liquibase-core library to version 4.9.0, I was having the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found workaround for this issue by upgrading liquibase to version 3.6 first and then I bumped it to 4.8. Everything is explained here on the issue that I have created on liquibase project repo: https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/issues/3109

Answer (score 0):

Is there a specific reason why you aren't updating to the most recent version?

As you note, the issue was fixed in 4.9.0. This PR has some details about how it was tested. You could try to replicate those tests using your configuration and see if it works. https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/pull/2589

I would recommend trying to update to 4.14 and see if the issue persists.